# How to get all the details of what will be executed in scenario

Tags: karate

How to know what all steps will run in any given scenario

With help of *karate.info* it provides scenario's meta data

```
{
  "featureDir": "/home/jai/IdeaProjects/learnings/src/test/java/examples/users",
  "scenarioType": "Scenario",
  "featureFileName": "users.feature",
  "errorMessage": null,
  "scenarioDescription": "",
  "scenarioName": "create a user and then get it by id"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. Steps are the responsibility of the `Feature`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt assistance, is there any way by which I can know what my scenario status is?

Comment: @JaikumarChandrapalka no. I think you have confused Karate with something else. please use Karate for testing. looks like someone has asked you to do all these things. please tell them it is a waste of time. use it for what it was designed to do.